# Why does my table and background not expand correctly LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx

I have an Image for drawing my background that I add to the stage. For some reason, there is a small space on the bottom - it's not laid out correctly

See attached image. I draw the background yellow to make it more visible. Why doesn't expand the background all the way to the bottom?

```
@Override
public void show() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);
    cam.position.set(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH / 2, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
    stage = new Stage(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, true);
    stage.setCamera(cam); // !IMPORTANT

    Image img = new Image(Assets.background);
    img.setFillParent(true);
    img.setSize(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);
    stage.addActor(img);
    Table table = new Table(skin);
    table.debug();
    table.setBounds(0, 0, Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);
    table.setFillParent(true);
    /* add all the menu items to table */
    stage.addActor(table);
}
```

RESOLUTION_WIDTH = 800
RESOLUTION_HEIGHT = 1280;

[image]

Comment: have you tried  stage = new Stage(Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT, false);

Comment: thanks, but this didn't work. It results in having the same border on top as well now. Any other ideas?

Comment: R u trying to hide that black border on the bottom of the image???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to hide the yellow part, which is the whole background. I assumed `setFillParent()` would do that, but as you can see in my code: it doesn't expand all the way down.

Comment: I couldnt find anything wrong in your code. Just try to draw the same image using simple batch.draw() ie no stage used. If you are still getting the same yellow space then check your image size.

Comment: That didn't work either with `batch.draw(Assets.background, 0, 0, Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT);`. The same problem.. I see that the table's debug border has also the wrong size (it doesn't go to the top and bottom) Could that be the problem? Event though I set `setFillParent()` on the table too

Comment: See if batch.draw(Assets.background, 0, 0, Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH, Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT); did not worked then it means that something is wrong either with your camera position or your image dimensions. I dont think there is any problem with your stage. check your image size(specially height , may be its 2 or 3 pixel less then resolutionHeight) and post it here.

Comment: the image dimension is 512x1024 pixels. But that should be up scaled by Android anyways, right? It must have something do with the camera or table, because it works on a different screen that has different world coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it would draw that border: 
I completely overlooked, that I implemented the resize method and did something weird with the zoom.

```
 cam.viewportHeight = height; //set the viewport
 cam.viewportWidth = width; 
 if (Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth < Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT / cam.viewportHeight)
 {
    //set the right zoom direct
    cam.zoom = Helper.RESOLUTION_HEIGHT / cam.viewportHeight;
 } else {
     //set the right zoom direct
     cam.zoom = Helper.RESOLUTION_WIDTH / cam.viewportWidth;
 }
 cam.update();
```

Leaving the resize function to its default implementation fixed the problem.
Thanks, Pranav008 for all the help though!